# no response for iPad to show excel cell data

Tags: ios, excel

I would like to read the excel file from my project folder at Xcode 5.1.1 using QZXLSReader Framework. When it comes to the execution. it does not work and show the required values.WOuld you please tell me are there any other alternatives to read excel data ? How to read the content of the excel files under project directory ?

[image]

The below is my output log  message

```
2014-06-13 16:25:13.558 marker[4130:60b] conetnt /var/mobile/Applications/D01BD499-C336-4A73-870A-6643B621E28E/marker.app/test_fr.xls
2014-06-13 16:25:13.559 marker[4130:60b] conetnt /var/mobile/Applications/D01BD499-C336-4A73-870A-6643B621E28E/marker.app/test_fr.xls
2014-06-13 16:25:13.560 marker[4130:60b] firstname (null)
```

The below is my code:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test_fr" ofType:@"xls"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
QZWorkbook *excelReader = [[QZWorkbook alloc] initWithContentsOfXLS:url];
NSArray *sheets =excelReader.workSheets;
NSMutableArray *words = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0 ; i < [sheets count] ; i ++){
    QZWorkSheet *sheet = [sheets objectAtIndex:i];
    NSArray *columns = [ sheet columns];
    NSArray *rows =  columns.firstObject;
    for(int  j = 0  ; j < [rows count] ; j ++){
        QZCell *nextObject =  [ rows objectAtIndex:j ] ;
        [words addObject:            nextObject.content ];
NSLog(@"%@", extObject.content);

    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated this question but no one seems can answer for it

Comment: did you found any solution.? I need to read xlsx file but i am unable to find any solution. @Raju yourPepe

Comment: probably not. csv instead

Answer (score -1):

I was using this framework, and not problems to show it,

I used:

```
NSUrl* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NameOfXls.xls"]]; // caminho do xls

QZWorkbook* excelReader = [[QZWorkbook alloc] initWithContentsOfXLS:url]; // pega o workbook
QZWorkSheet* firstWorkSheet = excelReader.workSheets.firstObject; // pega a primeira worksheet daquele workbook
[firstWorkSheet open];

NSLog(@"%@",firstWorkSheet.rows); // to show all rows, is obvious have some nulls values, check the output
```